# How to create flash screen like attached file below for andriod mobile

Tags: android, android-animation

I need small help or guidance. I have attached an image file.

It is splash screen design for Android:

[image: animated flash screen]

Can anyone please help me to know how we can create this kind of animation?

Comment: for me it looked like a pre-recorded video.

Comment: using a pre recorded video is easier to use here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something called [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)
It's an android library which natively renders Adobe After effects animation. You can use it for something this complex.

> Lottie is a mobile library for Android and iOS that parses Adobe After Effects animations exported as json with Bodymovin and renders them natively on mobile!